# Breaking up a sku into smaller portions

Tags: php, regex, split

I am trying to chunk my sku into smaller portions, unfortunetly the below code does not work as
sometimes my sku's are 12 digits, sometimes 10.

```
$this->skuMap['simple'][$sku] = [
    'RefId' => substr($sku, 0, 5),
    'Color' => substr($sku, 5, -3),
    'Name'  => $product->getName(),
];
```

I'm pretty sure there is a way to preg_split this, but I'm not certain of the regex, here was my failed attempt.

```
$sku = preg_split(['/^[0-9]{5}/','/([0-9]{5})([0-9]{3})/'], $sku, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: I have no idea, what a sku is, but can't you use `strlen()` if you have variable length?

Comment: How do you want them split? Can you give a couple examples of input and then the expected output?

Comment: If you're going to do this, you should really make a format *before* you generate them and have to split. Otherwise do a length check first.

Comment: @slapyo ([0-9]{5})([0-9]{3})([0-9]) would be the capture groups. Or, first five numbers, next three numbers, whatever numbers are left

Comment: @Amelia unfortunately I don't have the luxury of working with sanitized/sane data, otherwise this would be a non-issue.

Comment: What's the formats used? since preg splitting is fairly easy if we know.

Comment: @Amelia like I said above, I have numbers that can either be 12 or 10 digits, I need them broken up by the first 5 digits, next three digits, and whatever the remainder are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is `"/^([0-9]{5})([0-9]{3})([0-9]+)$/"`.

```
$matches = [];
if (preg_match("/^([0-9]{5})([0-9]{3})([0-9]+)$/", $string, $matches) !== -1) {

    $id = $matches[1];
    $color = $matches[2];
    $info = $matches[3];

} else {
    throw new \RuntimeException("bad SKU");
}
```

Broken down it's five digits, 3 digits, then any number of digits, each in separate groups.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting above, but this also works.

```
$this->skuMap['simple'][$sku] = [
    'RefId' => substr($sku,0,5),
    'Color' => substr(substr_replace($sku,'',0,5),0,3),
    'Name'  => $product->getName(),
];
```